# How to generate a Google-managed certificates for wildcard hostnames in GCP?

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform

I would like to use Google-managed certificates for wildcard hostnames—for example, `*.example.com`.

I know I could use Certificate Manager from the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/overview) in GCP, but I cannot find a concrete example.

Could you please show me some examples?

Comment: [Request a certificate using Certificate Manager Public CA](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/public-ca-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reference this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-manager/docs/deploy-google-managed-dns-auth#create_a_certificate_map_entry).

I need DNS authorization to provide a certificate with wildcard hostname.

I would like to post a concret example for this question in case anyone have the same doubts as me.

Most of the step could reference to the doc, I would like to point out two steps you need to take care of.

In `Create a Google-managed certificate referencing the DNS authorization` step, provide your single domain and your wildcard hostname in the `--domains` options.

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager certificates create my-cert \
    --domains="example.com,*.example.com" --dns-authorizations=my-dns-auth
```

In `Create a certificate map entry` step, create two entries for both single hostname and wildcard hostname.

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager maps entries create my-entry1 \
    --map="my-map" \
    --certificates="my-cert" \
    --hostname="example.com"
```

```bash
gcloud certificate-manager maps entries create my-entry2 \
    --map="my-map" \
    --certificates="my-cert" \
    --hostname="*.example.com"
```